# Java Split Text - Regular Expression or other: Date + Text Date + Text

Tags: java

I need to split a big Java String composed of dates and text (the date and the following text represent an entry).

Using Java code (regular expression or other method)

**Example of String**

```
String bigText = "2016-08-05 My Test 1 2016-08-04 My Test 2 2016-08-03 My Test 3 ...";
```

**The result must be:**

```
2016-08-05 My Test 1
2016-08-04 My Test 2
2016-08-03 My Test 3 
...
```

Any suggestion to split the string like that ?

I await your response as soon as possible.

Regards

Comment: Do you want to insert newline characters? Or is that result an array?

Comment: Can you update your question to show us what you have tried?

Comment: Find the space after `Test x` and split the string there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead to identify spaces which are followed by a date. You can either split, or replace it with a newline character.

```
\s(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

In order to split:

```
String[] output = input.split("\\s(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
```

In order to replace:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\\s(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})", "\n");
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mS5cZ2/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
String bigText = "2016-08-05 My Test 1 2016-08-04 My Test 2 2016-08-03 My Test 3 ...";     
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(bigText);     
int i = 0;
while ((i = str.indexOf(" ", i + 20)) != -1)
{
    str.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}    

System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Output:

> 2016-08-05 My Test 1
>   2016-08-04 My Test 2
>   2016-08-03 My Test 3
>   ...

<kbd>[View the Demo](https://ideone.com/wjPAIv)</kbd>